# How do I sort partition data when using query binding on an SSAS cube?

Tags: t-sql, ssas, olap, cube

I'm trying to implement various sorts as described in [this article](http://dennyglee.com/2013/09/30/analysis-services-multidimensional-it-is-the-order-of-things/).

I have a typical Sales Measure Group partitioned by fiscal period. If I try to add an `order by` clause to the query it fails when processing because SSAS wraps the query into a subquery. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? How do I ensure the sort order in a case like this?

Here is the code that is generated for a partition:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(  
SELECT *
FROM [Sales]
WHERE SaleDate between '1/1/2015' and '1/28/2015' 
order by SaleDate
)
AS [Sales]
```

I replaced the field names with * for clarity.

Comment: [`ORDER BY`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/97647)

Comment: Am I missing something? That sorts the attributes within a dimension. My understanding of the article is that the sort order of the data coming in from the Select query in your partition is what affects the compression of the bitmap indexes.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM Sales ORDER BY SaleDate
```

That is not guaranteed to work. The best way to order it is to ensure the clustered index is on the column you want to order by.

Comment: Yeah, I saw one article that indicated the query optimizer could ignore this if there was a better way to get the data. I saw another one that did `select top *rowcount* from Sales order by SaleDate`. That showed the sort in the query plan, but I'm not sure how repeatable it is.

Comment: Hi Greg, this didn't really solve my problem, so I wasn't going to mark it as answered.